# Custom style for buttons not work on pre-5.0 devices

Tags: android, button, styles

In styles.xml, I've defined a custom style for all buttons in my app like this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
</style>

 <style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">4dp</item>
</style>
```

This works on Android 5.0+ devices, but on pre-5.0 the buttons seem to use the default style.

My activity extends `ActionBarActivity`. However, If I set it to extend `Activity` and adjust app's theme to Holo, then it works on both 5.0 and pre-5.0 devices.

Any suggestion? Thanks ^^

---

Update:

I've changed `android:buttonStyle` to `buttonStyle` and it works now on both 5.0 and pre-5.0 devices, without any other modifications.

Comment: Does your activity extend `ActionBarActivity` or just `Activity`?

Comment: My activity extends ActionBarActivity. If I change to Activity and adjust app's theme to Holo, it works both 5.0 and pre-5.0 devices.

Comment: Okay. What happens on pre-5.0 devices? Does the app crash or does it use the default theme?

Comment: It didn't crash but the buttons seem to use the default style.